# Div with width auto, next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with 3 divs next to each other. The one on the left is constant and its width doesn't change. The center one needs to contract and expand according to the div on the right, as it is also expanding because it is a cart. I have the website available for you, so you can see the problem.

This is what I want:

```
[div=constant width]
[div=expanding/contracting]
[div=expanding/contracting]
```

Details:

- Site: http://ssdbutikken.dk/
- User: test
- Pass: qwertytest

Comment: The divs should ofc be next to each other. I've made a screenshot so you can se what i want. [http://ajytzler.dk/pics/width100problem.png](http://ajytzler.dk/pics/width100problem.png) So the search bar should ofc be where the red square is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display:table for this. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}
.left,.middle,.right{
  display:table-cell;
  background:red;
}
.left{
  width:100px;
}
.middle{
  background:yellow;
}
.right{
  background:blue;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jAquQ/

It's work till IE8 & above.

Comment: Using your suggestion, i think i got very much closer to the result. I just dont understand whats happening now. Could you take a look at my site, and see if you understand whats going wrong :-) Would be appreciated.

Comment: Give **display:table; width:100%** to Parent DIV (headerbar) & **display:table-cell** to it's Child DIV (module).

Answer (score 0):

```
.constant 
{
float:left;
width:200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.constant_2 
{
float:right;
width:700px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
<div>
<div class="constant "></div>
<div align="center"></div>

<div  class="constant_2 "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

float:left will do the work : try this

```
  <div style="float:left;background-color:red;width:200px">left</div>
  <div style="float:left;background-color:green">middle</div>
  <div style="float:left;background-color:blue">right</div>
```